# Term for chorus that sounds like pre-chorus

Tags: chord-progressions, terminology, pop-music

I'm not good with musical terms, but I like to listen to songs that have odd and strange parts while maintaining "good" structure.

There's a song called Remember Me by Oh My Girl. To my ear, the chorus part of this song sounds like a pre-chorus. It sounds like it's building tension for the chorus, but it suddenly disappears and then it goes to 2nd verse. It's around 00:45.

My question is what's the term for this kind of chorus? I've searched the internet and found nothing.

This is the song:

Comment: could you add to your question the timing in the video of the part you're referring to ? (ie how many ninutes in) It sounds to me like verse -> bridge -> chorus but the chorus part seems pretty straightforward to me, so I might be misunderstanding. Ta.

Comment: @user2808054 at 00:45. To me it sounds like a pre-chorus that's leading to a chorus. But near the end of that section I realize it's actually a chorus.

Comment: Ok thanks - If I was explaining how to play that to someone, I think I'd call that either a bridge, or just a chorus of two parts, because you have two lines similar starting at 0:45, then it bursts into life with something more fulsome at 1:01. I'll let others anwer if there's a technical name. A typical pop structure would be verse -> bridge (something a bit different) -> bouncy chorus but this seems to have verse -> bridge (rappy bit) -> chorus1 (0:45 boppy tune) -> chorus 2 (1:01 even boppier). Not unusual and seems to work. Not sure "Boppy tune" is a good technical term though lol